# How to write XPath to find proper value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have below two lines in my XML file in this sequence.

```
 <component group="digitalPass" name="count">1</component>
 <component group="digitalPass" name="selected_0">I</component>
```

I am writting below XPath and getting value as **"1"** but I want to take the value **"I"**

```
component [@group="digitalPass"]
```

so how can i specify name="selected_0" so that i get the desired result?

Comment: perhaps `component [@group="digitalPass" and @name="selected_0"]` is what you want?

Comment: @dutchdukes forget to update..
it has been resolved by this 
component [@group="digitalPass][@name="selected_0"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify the possible ways, if someone looks for:

**1. Using 'and' plus @name**

```
component[@group="digitalPass" and @name="selected_0"]
```

**2. Using two [ ]'s plus @name**

```
component[@group="digitalPass"][@name="selected_0"]
```

**3. Using 'and' plus text comparison**

```
component[@group="digitalPass" and text()="I"]
```

**4. Using two [ ]'s plus text comparison**

```
component[@group="digitalPass"][text()="I"]
```